# Ajax request not working when picking a color value for a table row

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

So I have a table that is set up like this:

```
$(document).ready(function($)
{    
function create_html_table (tbl_data)
{


    //--->create data table > start
    var tbl = '';
    tbl +='<table>'

        //--->create table header > start
        tbl +='<thead>';
            tbl +='<tr>';
            tbl +='<th>col1</th>';
            tbl +='<th>col2</th>';
            tbl +='<th>col3</th>';
            tbl +='</tr>';
        tbl +='</thead>';
        //--->create table header > end

        //--->create table body > start
        tbl +='<tbody>';


            //--->create table body rows > start
            $.each(tbl_data, function(index, val) 
            {
                //you can replace with your database row id
                var row_id = val['row_id'];

                //loop through ajax row data
                tbl +='<tr row_id="'+row_id+'" style="background-color:'+val['default_color']+'">';
                    tbl +='<td><label for="colorPicker_'+index+'">Color:</label><input type="color" class="colorpicker" value="'+val['default_color']+'" id="colorPicker_'+index+'"></td>'
                    tbl +='<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="col1">'+val['col1']+'</div></td>';
                    tbl +='<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="col2">'+val['col2']+'</div></td>';
                    tbl +='<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="col3">'+val['col3']+'</div></td>';

                    //--->edit options > end                        
                tbl +='</tr>';
            });
            //--->create table body rows > end
        tbl +='</tbody>';
        //--->create table body > end

    tbl +='</table>';
    //--->create data table > end

    //out put table data
    $(document).find('.tbl_user_data').html(tbl);
}


var ajax_url = "<?php echo APPURL;?>/ajax.php" ;
var ajax_data = <?php echo json_encode($q1);?>;

//create table on page load
//create_html_table(ajax_data);

//--->create table via ajax call > start
$.getJSON(ajax_url,{call_type:'get'},function(data) 
{
    create_html_table(data);
});
```

The purpose of this is to generate a table on ajax request from mysql table. Each row has a column called default_color that determines the color of the row in the initial styling of the row. I am trying to do an ajax request that changes the color for that row when the colorpicker is used so that he change is permanently stored in the database. Here is what I used in javascript for the colorpicker.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function () {

    $(document).on('change','.colorpicker',function(evt){
        var el=$(evt.target);
        var val=el.val(); 
        var tr=el.closest("tr");
        var data_obj = 
        {
            row_id: tr.attr("row_id"),
            col_name: "default_color",
            col_val:val,
            call_type: 'single_entry',              
        };
        $.post(ajax_url, data_obj, function(data) {

        })
    });
});



});

</script>
```

However, the ajax request to send the color picker value over isn't working and I'm not sure why. Everything else is editable and works fine. But this is causing issues.

This is how all other values are currently being updated

```
if(isset($_POST['call_type']) && $_POST['call_type'] =="single_entry")
{   

$row_id     = app_db()->CleanDBData($_POST['row_id']);
$col_name   = app_db()->CleanDBData($_POST['col_name']); 
$col_val    = app_db()->CleanDBData($_POST['col_val']);

$tbl_col_name = array("col1", "col2", "col3", "row_id");

if (!in_array($col_name, $tbl_col_name))
{
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 'error', 
        'msg' => 'invalid col_name', 
    ));
    die();
}

$q1 = app_db()->select("select * from users where row_id='$row_id'");
if($q1 < 1) 
{
    //no record found in the database
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 'error', 
        'msg' => 'no entries were found', 
    ));
    die();
}
else if($q1 > 0) 
{
    //found record in the database

    $strTableName = "users";

    $array_fields = array(
        $col_name => $col_val,
    );
    $array_where = array(    
      'row_id' => $row_id,
    );
    //Call it like this:  
    app_db()->Update($strTableName, $array_fields, $array_where);


    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 'success', 
        'msg' => 'updated entry', 
    ));
    die();
}
```

Comment: "the ajax request to send the color picker value over isn't working"  _in what way_ is it not working? What debugging have you done? Are you getting errors? If so, what are they? Is the request being sent?  If so, have you confirmed that it is sent as expected and have you checked the response?

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging, however you need to debug each mechanism separately. First, make sure the `$.post()` command sends the data properly: add `var_dump($_POST); die();` at the start of your PHP script and on the client log or alert the response. Next, check that the PHP code does what you think it does; `echo` various values and again check the reply on the server. Approach the goal step by step and you will quickly find the problem (I always did).

Comment: Why is the on change of colopicker inside the click of tr??  comment out the on click of tr, i think it should work.